# Animating a second hand

Tags: android, animation

How to animate a second hand of a analog clock with the pivot being the bottom center of the image(image link given below).

1. Currently the image rotates with center as pivot but I need the pivot to be bottom center indicated by the red dot in the image. I tried setting 0.5,1.0 and 1.0,0.5 but the image moves to a different region and is not pivoting at the correct point.
2. With the current animation the seconds hand sweeps smoothly, how to achieve stop and animate,stop and animate cycle similar to traditional analog clocks.

[image]

code that I am using is given below

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    seconds = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    seconds++;
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Canvas", "second is " + seconds);
            // imageView.animate()
            // .setDuration(1000)
            // .rotation(6f * seconds);
            RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(
                    (seconds - 1) * 6, seconds * 6,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

            rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            rotateAnimation.setDuration(1000);
            rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
            imageView.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            seconds++;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I used 0.5f and 1.0f as the pivot for rotation. The change needed is that ImageView height and width should be fixed. Earlier it was set to WRAP_CONTENT for both. which caused the image to shift before rotating.

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(
                (seconds - 1) * 6, seconds * 6,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f);
```

Answer (score 0):

The length of a second hand is approximately equal to radius of a circle or half the circle's diameter. Your origin of rotation for your second hand needs to be the center of that circle. Place the circle's center at a zero x y origin. place the base of the second hand on the zero origin. Rotation is relative to the circle's center.